# How can I avoid a stack overflow when Fortran produces a large, internal, temporary array?

Tags: fortran, stack-overflow, reshape, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have some Fortran code that calls `RESHAPE` to reorder a matrix such that the dimension that I am now about to loop over becomes the first varying dimension (Column-major order in Fortran).

This has nothing to do with C/Fortran interoperability.

Now the matrix is rather large and when I call the `RESHAPE` function I get a seg fault which I am very confident is a stack overflow. I know this because I can compile my code in ifort with `-heap-arrays` and the problem disappears.

I do not want to modify the stack-size. This code needs to be portable for any computer without the user having to concern himself with stack-size.

Is there someway I can get this call of the `RESHAPE` function to use the heap and not the stack for its internal memory use.

Worst case I will have to 'roll my own' `RESHAPE` function for this instance but I wish there was a better way.

Comment: Is the reshape cheaper than modifying your loop to handle how the array is structured?  (e.g. is a reshape really necessary?)

Comment: I believe it is. What I require are loop slices. Either I do some pre-processing with `reshape` to make those slices contiguous in memory up front or I produce slews of temporary arrays when I ask for non-contiguous pieces of memory.

Comment: The compiler creates a temporary. You cannot portably instruct it to place it on the heap without compiler options. I would do the transpose manually.

Comment: Why can't the complier just check the size of the temporary array requested, compare it to the stack size, and use the heap accordingly (hint hint Intel)?

Comment: Intel has provided the solution already; it is -heap-arrays. This option takes a size cutoff, too, which is exactly what you are suggesting.

Comment: @EMiller As Jeff says. Note that the Fortran standard does not speak about stack and heap at all, that is an implementation detail. Therefore, such behavior is controlled by compiler options (`-heap-arrays n` in ifort, `-fstack-arrays` in gfortran).

Comment: Well, we might as well make that into an answer. Would one of you post as such and we can close this?

Comment: it could be useful to show here how to do the manual transpose. Can you show a simple example of your `reshape` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fortran standard does not speak about stack and heap at all, that is an implementation detail. In which part of memory something is placed and whether there are any limits is implementation defined.

Therefore it is impossible to control the stack or heap behaviour from the Fortran code itself. The compiler must be instructed by other means if you want to specify this and the compiler options are used for that. Intel Fortran uses stack by default and has the `-heap-arrays n` option (n is the limit in kB), gfortran is slightly different and has the opposite `-fstack-arrays` option (included in `-Ofast`, but can be disabled).

This is valid for all kinds of temporaries and automatic arrays.

Comment: So the solution would be to look up the stack size and set  `-heap-arrays n` to make a reasonable guess as to what sized arrays would need to make it to the heap. The problem is, when one ships the compiled code out, if the user doesn't have the same stack size, then this method will still fail. So the only robust way to do it is to use `-heap-arrays` which just puts everything on the heap and you lose the advantage of a stack.

Comment: You can quite safely put there couple of kB, otherwise you would have to avoid any recursion too as it grows the stack.

Comment: @EMiller You should check but iirc ifort doesn't actually honor the argument to `-heap-arrays` and just puts everything on the heap. The last version I used though was 14 so that may have changed since then.