# Segmentation fault with automatic arrays

Tags: memory-management, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm writing a program, which should calculate the inverse of a big sparse matrix (n > 1000) and need a full identity matrix during the calculation. I want to create this identity matrix as automatic data object.

At this point, I have the problem that the program gets *sometimes* stuck during access to the computational routine (in this case MKL's PARDISO).

To investigate the problem, I used `valgrind` and several compiler versions of `ifort`. I wrote a small sample program showing the same behaviour while watched by valgrind. Unfortunately, it doesn't crash while running on its own.

```
module testmod
  implicit none
contains

  subroutine testsub(nl)
    integer :: nl, i, j
    !complex(8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: b
    complex(8), dimension(nl,nl) :: b

    write(*,*) "Entering testsub"

    !allocate(b(nl,nl))
    b = 0

    write(*,*) sum(b)
    !deallocate(b)
  end subroutine
end module

program testprog
  use testmod
  implicit none

  call testsub(2000)

end program
```

I could detect a segmentation fault using `ifort 14, 15 and 16` at the first `write` statement. At least for `ifort 16` it starts at `n=1023`. Starting from `n=354`, `valgrind` detects invalid reads and writes (all 3 lines in the subroutine) and warns about a possible stack switch.

Replacing the automatic allocation with manual management (using the commented lines above), the problem seems to be solved.

What is the problem with the code? Are there size limits? Or is `ifort` broken (`gfortran` works fine)?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30511136/721644 I think it is a common stack overflow.

Comment: @VladimirF Indeed, this solved the problem. However, I'm still confused why this results in a stack overflow. Where are the limits of `2MB` and `16MB` resulting in the errors (invalid read/write and segfault, resp.) defined?

Comment: This is just the size of your stack which differs between computers, OS settings and so on. Valgrind can find when you access what you shouldn't in the given context, but is still within the limits allowed to the program as a whole. It crashes at 16 MB where you exceed the limits allowed by the OS.